# How to configuring slf4j with log4j in EAR on Glassfish

Tags: jakarta-ee, logging, glassfish, log4j, slf4j

I am trying to package 2 projects (ExampleWeb.war and ExampleEJb.jar) in a single `EAR` file. Every thing works fine except the logging thing. There is no error, but even log messages are not displayed on `Glassfish` server. not console no where.
Here are the contents of my ear file

```
Example.ear
    ExampleWeb.war
    ExampleEJB.jar
    lib
        log4j.properties
        slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar
        slf4j-log4j12-1.7.12.jar
        log4j-1.2.17.jar
    META-INF
        application.xml
```

Contents of the `application.xml` are as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:application="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_6.xsd" id="Application_ID" version="6">
  <display-name>Example</display-name>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>ExampleWeb.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>/</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
  <module>
    <ejb>ExampleEJB.jar</ejb>
  </module>
  <library-directory>lib</library-directory>
</application>
```

Please note I am able to call an `EJB` from web project using its `remote` interface and that hello method successfully write a message to console, using `System.out.println("hello");` how ever there is nothing happening for `log.info("hello from log");`

here is how I initialized the log object

```
//import statement
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

//variable initialization
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HelloFacade.class);
```

Here are the contents of `log4j.properties` file

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=FILE,console

# ------------- Console
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{ISO8601}]%5p%6.6r[%t]%x - %C.%M(%F:%L) - %m%n
log4j.appender.console.Threshold=INFO

# ---------------- File
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/logs/log4j.log
# Archive log files (one backup file here)
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxBackupIndex=2
# Control the maximum log file size
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxFileSize=1000KB
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{ISO8601}]%5p%6.6r[%t]%x - %C.%M(%F:%L) - %m%n
log4j.appender.FILE.Threshold=INFO
```

**Point to be noted**

1. There is no `slf4*.jar` can be found in `GlassFish` except with in application deployed folder.
2. There is no other `log4j.properties` in `GlassFish` except with in application deployed folder.

I have tried lot of things but unable to figure out the logging thing Please help me to fix it.

**Multiple test**
I have ran multiple test where I have removed jar files and placed them in ear's lib folder, kept the log4j.properties file in almost every folder of EAR file (rootfolder, classes folder, lib folder, META-INFO folder) but it has no impact at all, No error and no logging.

**I would be really amazed if someone does not know how to achieve this (logging, EAR[with multiple jar and war files], and Glassfish)**

Answer (score 0):

Put your `log4j.properties` file within a JAR file (you can name it as `loggin.jar`, etc.). And this JAR file you will put it in the `lib` folder (the same where are the libraries of log4j and SLF4J).